# Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed on spring integration application startup

Tags: java, java-8, spring-integration, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a spring integration application, and it fails on startup on Windows (Windows Server 2012 R2), using jdk1.8.0_151-X64 with the following exception :

```
INFO [main] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:574] Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b604f19: startup date [Thu Jul 04 15:17:39 CEST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
INFO [main] o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:317] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [cpm-dml-common-error.xml]
INFO [main] o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:317] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/D:/CPM/dml/adapter-versions/cpm-dml-subscriber-bla-1.2.0.RELEASE/lib/cpm-dml-common-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/dml-file-shutdown.xml]
ERROR [main] c.h.g.d.i.u.Adapter [Adapter.java:73] Exception initialising application context.  Process will exit
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:dml-file-shutdown.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [cpm-dml-subscriber-bla-top-level.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/D:/CPM/dml/adapter-versions/cpm-dml-subscriber-bla-1.2.0.RELEASE/lib/cpm-dml-common-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/dml-file-shutdown.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:165) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at c.h.g.d.i.u.Adapter.<init>(Adapter.java:47) ~[dml_core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at c.h.g.d.i.u.Adapter.main(Adapter.java:70) ~[dml_core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/D:/CPM/dml/adapter-versions/cpm-dml-subscriber-bla-1.2.0.RELEASE/lib/cpm-dml-common-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/dml-file-shutdown.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:223) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed
    at sun.security.provider.NativeSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(NativeSeedGenerator.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:144) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:221) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:145) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.integration.jmx.config.MBeanExporterParser.resolveId(MBeanExporterParser.java:87) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:64) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.xml.AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.parse(AbstractIntegrationNamespaceHandler.java:58) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

The application is the only java process running on the server. Restarting the application does not work, the same exception keeps coming.

I've tested running other spring integration applications on jdk1.7.0_11-x64, they run fine most of the time, but they still sometimes (~1/20) encounter this exception : a simple restart fixes the issue.

What is the likely cause of this Exception ? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is some kind of bug on Java side: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057894

At the same time your stack trace leads us to this code in the `MBeanExporterParser`:

```
if (id.matches(IntegrationMBeanExporter.class.getName() + "#[0-9]+")) {
        //  Randomize the name in case there are multiple contexts in the same JVM
        id += "#" + UUID.randomUUID();
    }
```

Would you mind to add an explicit `id` for your `<int-jmx:mbean-export>`  ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have at least 2 sides:

- A code trying to generate random numbers, part of Spring in this case.
- The JDK code responsible to generate the actual random number based on a security provider. sun.security.provider.Sun.

Given this is an intermittent issue (1/20 as mentioned initially), most likely is due to lock contention or slowness at the security provider end.

One solution is trying to minimize the calls to random numbers, configuring properly the Spring mbeans in this case.

However, the random number generation is not only linked to Spring mbeans, so the same underlying problem can be seen in different APIs, that's the 2nd part of this problem. sun.security.provider.Sun is the default security provider for the JDK or at least the first on the list of security providers at JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security file, and responsible to generate these random numbers.

The second aspect of this problem is that the random number generation is not just related to Spring mbeans; rather, it is related to a variety of APIs, where the same fundamental issue can be seen.
sun.security.provider.Sun is in charge of generating these random numbers and is the default security provider for the JDK, or at least the first on the list of security providers in the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java . security file.

For example:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Note the problematic security provider is on the top of the list, thus a second potential solution is disabling it, meaning that list with the indexes should be restructured to:

```
    security.provider.1=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign    
    #security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
    security.provider.2=sun.security.ec.SunEC
    security.provider.3=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
    security.provider.4=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
    security.provider.5=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
    security.provider.6=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
    security.provider.7=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
    security.provider.8=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
    security.provider.9=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Take a backup copy of the java.security file before, and try first in a non-productive environment.